# ValidateCredentials will only always return false in C#

Tags: c#, windows, powershell, authentication

I want to be able to validate that the credentials are correct for a particular user.

```
    public static void DomainVerification(string username, string password)
    {
        bool valid = false;
        using (PrincipalContext context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "domain.com"))
        {
            valid = context.ValidateCredentials(username, password);
        }
}
```

I'm not quite sure what I am doing wrong, if it's an invalid domain or invalid user/pass combo..

Within powershell, I am validating the domain with `wmic computersystem get domain` and running `whomai` to get the proper username.

What could be causing valid to always be false?

Comment: You could try by not passing the domain name (if the users are in the same domain your app is running on), and you could try to use UserManager.FindUser to determine if the user can be found

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto - good advice.  You usually don't need to specify domain name unless you are in a forest.

Comment: Hey guys, thanks. Removed the domain. Realized one issue testing on corporate machine was validation was going through Kerberos. After switching to VM on azure, removing the domain aspect fixed